# Using the URLconf defined in myworld.urls

Tags: python, django

[My directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csb5V.png)
index.html:

```
<h1>Members</h1>

<table border="1">
  {% for x in mymembers %}
  <tr>
    <td><a href="update/{{x.id}}" style="decoration: none">{{x.id}}</a></td>
    <td>{{ x.f_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.l_name }}</td>
    <td><a href="delete/{{x.id}}">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>

<p>
  <a href="add/" style="decoration: none">Add members</a>
</p>
```

update.html:

```
<h1>Update member</h1>

<form action="updaterecord/{{mymember.id}}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %} First Name:<br />
  <input name="first" value="{{mymember.f_name}}" />
  <br /><br />
  Last Name:<br />
  <input name="last" value="{{members.l_name}}" />
  <br /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

members/url.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('add/', views.add, name='add'),
    path('add/addrecord/', views.addrecord, name='addrecord'),
    path('delete/<int:id>', views.delete, name='delete'),
    path('update/<int:id', views.update, name='update'),
    path('update/updaterecord/<int:id>',
         views.updaterecord, name='updaterecord'),

]
```

myworld/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include,path

urlpatterns = [
    path('members/', include('members.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

the url:http://127.0.0.1:8000/members/update

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FBlw.png)

it might be a silly mistake or something but i cant just figure it out...help is appreciated!thanks

Comment: Yes, you are missing a closing `>` in your url patterns of update view.

Comment: gosh i feel stupid! anyways.. thanks man!